# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number problema no insert

Tags: php, pdo, crud

Preciso inserir através de um formulário os seguintes dados:

- TITULO
- DESCRIÇÃO
- PRECO

HTML:

```
    <?php 
session_start();
session_destroy(); 
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="inserir.php" method="post" target="_self">
    <label for="email">Titulo:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" value="">
    <br>

    <label for="senha">Descrição:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="descricao" name="descricao" value="">
    <br>
    <label for="senha">Preço:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="preco" name="preco" value="">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" id="acao" name="acao" value="cadastrar">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

INSERIR.PHP

```
    <?php 
try { 

$titulo = $_REQUEST['titulo'];
$descricao = $_REQUEST['descricao'];
$preco = $_REQUEST['preco'];

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=diner', 'root', ''); 
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO prato(titulo, descricao, preco) VALUES(:titulo, :descricao, :preco)'); 
    $stmt->execute(array( ':titulo' => '$titulo' )); 
    $stmt->execute(array( ':descricao' => '$descricao' )); 
    $stmt->execute(array( ':preco' => '$preco' )); 
    echo $stmt->rowCount();
     } catch(PDOException $e) { 
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
?>
```

A partir dai já não tenho sucesso.. aparece o seguinte erro:
**Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens**

minha tabela é: PRATO
e possui as colunas:
prato_id = int = primary
titulo = varchar
descricao = varchar
preco = varchar
sei que preciso gerar um numero de ID, pois isso não vai ser pelo usuário, e não sei como fazer.

segundo, após feito o registro desses dados, como faço um lista da tabela impressa no HTML ? mostrando os itens cadastrados ?

e por ultimo, excluir algum id.

estou a 2 dias rodando a internet buscando aprender sobre CRUD E PDO, mas empaquei nisso.

Comment: Acho que [*essa questão*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392424/pdo-bindparam-vs-execute) pode ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado Papa, realmente ajudou ! respondi com a solução.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Significa que o número de parâmetros passados na consulta não é igual ao número de colunas ou vice versa. No seu código são efetuadas 3 consultas que passam apenas um parâmetro.

```
$stmt->execute(array(':titulo' => '$titulo')); 
$stmt->execute(array(':descricao' => '$descricao')); 
$stmt->execute(array(':preco' => '$preco'));
```

Existem duas formas de fazer o bind entre os marcadores(named placeholders) e o valores, a primeira é especificar cada valor individualmente com `bindValue()` ou `bindParam()` a diferença entre esses dois métodos é que no primeiro é permitido passar valores diretamente enquanto o segundo só aceita referências(variáveis) retorno de função ou método geram o erro: `Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference`

**Forma com bindValue/bindParam**

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO prato(titulo, descricao, preco) VALUES(:titulo, :descricao, :preco)'); 
$stmt->bindValue(':titulo', $titulo)); 
$stmt->bindValue(':descricao', $descricao)); 
$stmt->bindValue(':preco', $preco));
$stmt->execute();
```

**Forma com execute**

Com `execute()` é possível passar todos os parâmetros de uma vez através de um array, é bastante útil em consultas dinâmicas.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO prato(titulo, descricao, preco) VALUES(:titulo, :descricao, :preco)');
$stmt->execute(array(':titulo' => $titulo, ':descricao' => $descricao, ':preco' => $preco));
```

Comment: eu consigo fazer isso com select tambem? 
 `$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT FROM prato VALUES(titulo, descricao, preco)');?>`  e printar o resultado na tela para uma paginação? aqui tentei usar o `->select();` mas da o seguinte erro:
` Fatal error: Call to undefined method Conexao::select()  `

Comment: @manzetti.denis, no `SELECT` não tem `VALUES`, os nomes dos campos vão antes do `FROM`, esse erro significa que não existe nenhum método com esse nome na classe Conexao. É melhor abrir uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 4):

Consegui resolvendo da seguinte forma:

No banco de dados, alterei a coluna **id_prato** para `auto-increment`.

o código ficou assim:

```
<?php
```

try {

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=diner', 'root', ''); 
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$pdo = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO prato VALUES(DEFAULT, :titulo, :descricao, :preco)'); //Preparando os dados
$pdo->bindValue( ':titulo' , $_REQUEST['titulo']); // recebendo dados do formulario
$pdo->bindValue( ':descricao' , $_REQUEST['descricao']); 
$pdo->bindValue( ':preco' , $_REQUEST['preco']); 
$pdo->execute(); // salvando no banco
echo $pdo->rowCount(); // retorna quantas linhas foram alteradas.
 } catch(PDOException $e) { 
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();}
```

?>