# Erro em código PHP de "Invalid parameter number" em código de venda que deve repor ou retirar a quantidade de produtos em outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Meu código envolve a atualização de uma venda PHP deve realizar duas ações quando atualizados:

- Fazer o cálculo total da venda na tabela `itens_venda`(caso a coluna quantidade seja alterada deva fazer um novo cálculo. STATUS: Executa)
- Repor a quantidade ou retirar da tabela `produto` (STATUS: Não executa).

Vou explicar com um exemplo:

- Existem uma **quantidade de 15 produtos** de um registro da tabela `produto`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- E foram vendidos uma **quantidade de 5 produtos** na tabela `itens_venda`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Caso a **quantidade de 5 fosse alterada para um valor menor para 2** os 3 produtos voltariam para
  o registro da tabela `produto`, ficando com o total de **18 produtos ao invés de 15**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- E a tabela `itens_venda` registraria **2 produtos vendidos ao invés de 5**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Caso a **quantidade de 5 fosse alterada para um valor maior para 7** haveria uma retirada de mais 2 produtos do registro da tabela `produto`, ficando com o total de **13 produtos ao invés de 15**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- E a tabela `itens_venda` registraria **7 produtos vendidos ao invés de 5**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que o seguinte erro acontecesse:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
Linha do erro: $quantidade_produto->execute();
```

- Formulário de atualização da venda

```
<form method="POST">
    <p> ID item venda:
    <select name="cd_itens_venda" required="">
            <option value=""> </option>
            <?php
                foreach ($resultado_vendas as $valor) {
                    echo "<option value='{$valor['cd_itens_venda']}'>{$valor['cd_itens_venda']}</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        </p>

        <p> ID produto:
            <select name="cd_produto" required="">
                <option value=""> </option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($resultado_produto as $v1) {
                        echo "<option value='{$v1['cd_produto']}'>{$v1['nome']}</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p> ID funcionário:
            <select name="cd_funcionario" required="">
                <option value=""> </option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($resultado_funcionario as $v2) {
                        echo "<option value='{$v2['cd_funcionario']}'>{$v2['nome']}</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>

        <p> ID cliente:
            <select name="cd_cliente" required="">
                <option value=""> </option>
                <?php
                    foreach ($resultado_cliente as $v3) {
                        echo "<option value='{$v3['cd_cliente']}'>{$v3['nome']}</option>";
                    }
                ?>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p> Pagamento:
            <select name="tipo_pagamento" required="">
                <option value=""> </option>
                <option value="Pagamento á vista">Pagamento á vista</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p> Valor do item: <input type="text" name="valor_item" step="0.01" required=""> </p>
        <p> Quantidade: <input type="number" name="quantidade" size="30" required=""> </p>
        <button name="Atualizar"> Atualizar item de venda </button>
</form>
```

- Código PHP completo

```
<?php
    require_once 'conexao.php'; 

    if(isset($_POST['Atualizar'])){
        // Especifica a variável
        $cd_itens_venda = $_POST['cd_itens_venda'];
        $cd_produto = $_POST['cd_produto'];
        $cd_funcionario = $_POST['cd_funcionario'];
        $cd_cliente = $_POST['cd_cliente'];
        $tipo_pagamento = $_POST['tipo_pagamento'];
        $valor_item = $_POST['valor_item'];
        $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
        // Cálcula o valor total da compra multiplicando o valor com a quantidade
        $valor_total = ($valor_item * $quantidade);
        try {
            // Tabela ITENS_VENDA
            $conexao->beginTransaction();
            $atualizacao = "UPDATE itens_venda SET cd_produto = :cd_produto, 
            cd_funcionario = :cd_funcionario, cd_cliente = :cd_cliente, 
            tipo_pagamento = :tipo_pagamento, valor_item = :valor_item, 
            quantidade = :quantidade, valor_total = :valor_total WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda";
            $atualiza_dados = $conexao->prepare($atualizacao);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':cd_itens_venda',$cd_itens_venda);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':cd_produto',$cd_produto);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':cd_funcionario',$cd_funcionario);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':cd_cliente',$cd_cliente);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':tipo_pagamento',$tipo_pagamento);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':valor_item',$valor_item);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':quantidade',$quantidade);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':valor_total',$valor_total);
            $atualiza_dados->execute();

            // Tabel PRODUTO
            // Query que faz o cálculo da diferença do produto atualizado
            $nova_quantidade = "UPDATE itens_venda SET quantidade = quantidade - :quantidade 
            WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda";
            // Query que faz a busca do registro do produto para fazer a reposição
            $procurar_produto = "SELECT quantidade FROM produto WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto";
            // Condicional para saber se vai tirar ou adicionar mais produtos
            if ($nova_quantidade < $quantidade) {
                // Haverá retirada de produto (caso a nova quantidade seja menor que a antiga)
                $calculo_reposicao = "UPDATE produto SET quantidade = '$procurar_produto' - quantidade WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto";
            }else{
                // Haverá reposição do produto (caso a nova quantidade seja maior que a antiga)
                $calculo_reposicao = "UPDATE produto SET quantidade = '$procurar_produto' + quantidade WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto";
            }
            $quantidade_produto = $conexao->prepare($calculo_reposicao);
            $quantidade_produto->bindValue(':cd_itens_venda',$cd_itens_venda);
            $quantidade_produto->bindValue(':cd_produto',$cd_produto);
            $quantidade_produto->bindValue(':quantidade',$quantidade);
            $quantidade_produto->execute(); // Linha do erro
            $conexao->commit();
                
        } catch (PDOException $falha_atualizacao) {
            echo "A atualização não foi feita".$falha_atualizacao->getMessage();
        }
    }
    // Query que seleciona chave de itens_venda
    $seleciona_vendas = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_itens_venda FROM itens_venda");
    // Resulta em uma matriz
    $resultado_vendas = $seleciona_vendas->fetchAll();  

    // Query que seleciona chave e nome do produto
    $seleciona_produto = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_produto, nome FROM produto");
    // Resulta em uma matriz
    $resultado_produto = $seleciona_produto->fetchAll();

    // Query que seleciona chave e nome do funcionario
    $seleciona_funcionario = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_funcionario, nome FROM funcionario");
    // Resulta em uma matriz
    $resultado_funcionario = $seleciona_funcionario->fetchAll();
        
    // Query que seleciona chave e nome do cliente
    $seleciona_cliente = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_cliente, nome FROM cliente");
    // Resulta em uma matriz
    $resultado_cliente = $seleciona_cliente->fetchAll();    
?>
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [SQLSTATE\[HY093\]: Invalid parameter number problema no insert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64382/sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-problema-no-insert)

Comment: Em relação a sua pergunta, os parâmetros da query não estão definidos corretamente, mas isso ocorre pq vc está confundindo o que é realmente uma query. Aqui `if ($nova_quantidade < $quantidade)`, por exemplo, vc está comparando uma string com o que é enviado via post. O mesmo erro acontece outras vezes, como na atribuição de `$calculo_reposicao`. Nem olhei o restante pq é preciso refazer provavelmente tudo...

Comment: Esse erro acontece quando existe um parametro a mais ou a menos na consulta, no update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Invalid parameter number` - o erro significa que há uma quantidade de parâmetros inválidos entre os Binds e a SQL

**As variáveis** $`procurar_produto` e `$nova_quantidade` devem retornar algo similar a:

$procurar_produto: `SELECT quantidade FROM produto WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto`

$nova_quantidade: `UPDATE itens_venda SET quantidade = quantidade - :quantidade WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda`

**o que não é o desejado**

> Comparando `$nova_quantidade < $quantidade` vai cair sempre no `else` da condicional

```
"UPDATE produto SET quantidade = '$procurar_produto' + quantidade WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto";
```

> e substituindo

`$procurar_produto` por `SELECT quantidade FROM produto WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto`

> deve gerar uma query assim

```
UPDATE produto SET quantidade = 'SELECT quantidade FROM produto WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto' + quantidade WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto
```

> a qual não vai executar absolutamente nada.

---

---

Diante de tais problemas fiz as devidas correções e acredito que vá funcionar a contento e isso você que vai me dizer.

**O código está comentado**

```
<?php

   require_once 'conexao.php';

    if(isset($_POST['Atualizar'])){
        // Especifica a variável
        $cd_itens_venda = $_POST['cd_itens_venda'];
        $cd_produto = $_POST['cd_produto'];
        $cd_funcionario = $_POST['cd_funcionario'];
        $cd_cliente = $_POST['cd_cliente'];
        $tipo_pagamento = $_POST['tipo_pagamento'];
        $valor_item = $_POST['valor_item'];
        $quantidade = $_POST['quantidade'];
        // Cálcula o valor total da compra multiplicando o valor com a quantidade
        $valor_total = ($valor_item * $quantidade);

        
        try {
        
            // Quantidade inicial na tabela itens_venda
            $procurar_produto = "SELECT quantidade FROM itens_venda WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto";
            $busca_registro = $conexao->prepare($procurar_produto);
            $busca_registro->bindValue(':cd_produto',$cd_produto);
            $busca_registro->execute();
            $linha = $busca_registro->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $quantidade_antiga = $linha['quantidade'];        
        
        
            // Tabela ITENS_VENDA
            $conexao->beginTransaction();
            $atualizacao = "UPDATE itens_venda SET cd_produto = :cd_produto, 
            cd_funcionario = :cd_funcionario, cd_cliente = :cd_cliente, 
            tipo_pagamento = :tipo_pagamento, valor_item = :valor_item, 
            quantidade = :quantidade, valor_total = :valor_total WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda";
            $atualiza_dados = $conexao->prepare($atualizacao);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':cd_itens_venda',$cd_itens_venda);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':cd_produto',$cd_produto);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':cd_funcionario',$cd_funcionario);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':cd_cliente',$cd_cliente);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':tipo_pagamento',$tipo_pagamento);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':valor_item',$valor_item);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':quantidade',$quantidade);
            $atualiza_dados->bindValue(':valor_total',$valor_total);
            $atualiza_dados->execute();

            // Tabel PRODUTO
            // Query que faz o cálculo da diferença do produto atualizado
            
            /* #########  serve pra nada pode excluir #######################################
            $nova_quantidade = "UPDATE itens_venda SET quantidade = quantidade - :quantidade 
            WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda";
            ############################################################################### */           
            
            
            // Condicional para saber se vai tirar ou adicionar mais produtos
            // fiz algumas correções nessa lógica e acho que dá para entender

            if ($quantidade < $quantidade_antiga) {
                // Haverá reposição do produto (caso a nova quantidade seja menor que a antiga)
                $calculo_reposicao = "UPDATE produto SET quantidade = quantidade + ('$quantidade_antiga'-:quantidade) WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto";
            }else{
                // Haverá retirada de produto (caso a nova quantidade seja maior que a antiga)
                $calculo_reposicao = "UPDATE produto SET quantidade = quantidade - (:quantidade-'$quantidade_antiga') WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto";
            }
            
            $quantidade_produto = $conexao->prepare($calculo_reposicao);

    /* linha indevida ################################################ */
    //$quantidade_produto->bindValue(':cd_itens_venda',$cd_itens_venda);
    /* ############################################################### */

            $quantidade_produto->bindValue(':cd_produto',$cd_produto);
            $quantidade_produto->bindValue(':quantidade',$quantidade);
            $quantidade_produto->execute();
            $conexao->commit();
              
        } catch (PDOException $falha_atualizacao) {
            echo "A atualização não foi feita".$falha_atualizacao->getMessage();
        }
    }
    // Query que seleciona chave de itens_venda
    $seleciona_vendas = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_itens_venda FROM itens_venda");
    // Resulta em uma matriz
    $resultado_vendas = $seleciona_vendas->fetchAll();  

    // Query que seleciona chave e nome do produto
    $seleciona_produto = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_produto, nome FROM produto");
    // Resulta em uma matriz
    $resultado_produto = $seleciona_produto->fetchAll();

    // Query que seleciona chave e nome do funcionario
    $seleciona_funcionario = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_funcionario, nome FROM funcionario");
    // Resulta em uma matriz
    $resultado_funcionario = $seleciona_funcionario->fetchAll();
        
    // Query que seleciona chave e nome do cliente
    $seleciona_cliente = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_cliente, nome FROM cliente");
    // Resulta em uma matriz
    $resultado_cliente = $seleciona_cliente->fetchAll();    

?>
```

---

### No caso de delete é como segue

```
<?php
require_once 'conexao.php';  
    if(isset($_POST['Deletar'])){
    // Especifica a variável
    $cd_itens_venda = $_POST['cd_itens_venda'];
    try {
            $conexao->beginTransaction();
            // Quantidade inicial na tabela itens_venda
            $procurar_produto = "SELECT cd_produto,quantidade FROM itens_venda WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda";
            $busca_registro = $conexao->prepare($procurar_produto);
            $busca_registro->bindValue(':cd_itens_venda',$cd_itens_venda);
            $busca_registro->execute();
            $linha = $busca_registro->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            
            //variaveis a serem usadas no update da tabela produto
            
            $quantidade = $linha['quantidade']; 
            $cd_produto = $linha['cd_produto'];
        
        
        // TABELA ITENS_VENDA
        $remove = "DELETE FROM itens_venda WHERE cd_itens_venda = :cd_itens_venda";
        $remocao = $conexao->prepare($remove);
        $remocao->bindValue(':cd_itens_venda',$cd_itens_venda);
        $remocao->execute();
       
        // Query que faz a atualização da quantidade de estoque da tabela produto
        $atualiza_quantidade = "UPDATE produto SET quantidade = quantidade + ('$quantidade') WHERE cd_produto = '$cd_produto'";
        $quantidade_produto = $conexao->prepare($atualiza_quantidade);
        $quantidade_produto->execute(); 
        
        $conexao->commit();
    } catch (PDOException $falha_remocao) {
        echo "A remoção não foi feita".$falha_remocao->getMessage();
    }
}
// Query que seleciona o registro de itens_venda
$seleciona_nomes = $conexao->query("SELECT cd_itens_venda FROM itens_venda");
// Resulta em uma matriz
$resultado_selecao = $seleciona_nomes->fetchAll();      
?>
```

Comment: o código de atualização da venda está funcionando, mais o código de exclusão do registro da venda está aparecendo um erro ```A remoção não foi feitaThere is already an active transaction```

Comment: Desculpe, foi um erro meu os dois códigos funcionam, obrigado Leo se minha(s) dúvidas(s) com recompensa(s) não fosse fechada eu aceitaria a sua resposta como a melhor.

Comment: @Vorbbel, a maior recompensa é saber que você foi ajudado e eu participei dessa alegria :-)

Comment: variável $humildade foi declarada com sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Tudo bem?

Pelo que notei, o erro acontece porque você está dando bind em tokens que não existem.

Note que a sua variável da query está assim:

```
$calculo_reposicao = "UPDATE produto SET quantidade = '$procurar_produto' - quantidade WHERE cd_produto = :cd_produto";
```

O único token dela é :cd_produto.

Porem no objeto você está colocando

```
$quantidade_produto->bindValue(':cd_produto',$cd_produto);
$quantidade_produto->bindValue(':quantidade',$quantidade);
```

O seu erro está vindo dessa variável quantidade, que não existe na query. tente tirar esta variável e vê se funciona.

Abs

Answer (score 0):

Fala amigo, tudo certo? Você não está passando **:cd_itens_venda** e **:quantidade** na query **$calculo_reposicao** mas está dando *bind* nelas.

Tem *quantidade* mas está sem os **:** na query para referenciar:

```
[..]SET quantidade = '$procurar_produto' - /*faltam os dois pontos (:) aqui */quantidade WHERE cd_produto[...]
```

Basta remover essas linhas:

```
$quantidade_produto->bindValue(':cd_itens_venda',$cd_itens_venda);
$quantidade_produto->bindValue(':quantidade',$quantidade); //Remova esta linha se não for usar o :quantidade na query $calculo_reposicao.
```

*Obs: Não sei se passou resumido o código mas está faltando executar as duas queries das variáveis para obter o total: **$nova_quantidade** e **$procurar_produto***

Abraços!